# Install XDebug and load in Acquia Drupal Stack?

Tags: php, apache, macos, drupal, xdebug

I am trying to follow this article:

http://robshouse.net/article/xdebug-komodo-and-acquia-drupal-stack-installer

I did all of that, yet XDebug is still not being loaded or shown on phpinfo.

Has anyone got this to successfully work?

I installed XDebug with Homebrews, brew install xdebug. I copied xdebug.so to my acquia stack folder, /php/ext/xdebug.so and added the approrpiate lines to php.ini, restarted the stack and Apache and no luck.

Tried a few different articles and have not had success.

My php.ini:

```
[debug]
; Remote settings
zend_extension=/Applications/acquia-drupal/php/ext/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

This is reported in my apache errors:

```
Failed loading /Applications/acquia-drupal/php/ext/xdebug.so
```

But the file does exist there.

Comment: @Kevin - to quickest way to check xdebug is compiled and loaded properly into PHP is `var_dump`, xdebug will alter the var_dump format into some nice format, maybe u can check that first?

Comment: No, it doesn't show it at all.

Comment: @Kevin - file permission issue?  at least a 600 or readable for your apache

Comment: Yep, file permissions are straight. The files are owned as root, will that matter?

Comment: @Kevin - if the owned by root, is your apache run as root ? try login as 2 different user, root and the user that running apache, in CLI - `php -r "echo 1;" check did PHP complain any error

Comment: Nothing I have done so far has got this to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the XDebug to work either with Homebrew.

Get the working xdebug.so from ActiveState.
http://code.activestate.com/komodo/remotedebugging/

Article about this:
http://debuggable.com/posts/setting-up-xdebug-on-mac-os-x-or-win32-linux:480f4dd6-0240-4a90-8fa1-4e41cbdd56cb

Comment: Interesting. I will have to give this a shot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The author of robshouse.net moved his website to Drupal Gardens and did not migrate the article linked to in the question.  However the article is somewhat outdated.

You do not need to download anything to enable xdebug in current versions of Acquia Dev Desktop.

Simply uncomment the line that mentions xdebug in /Applications/acquia-drupal/php5_*/bin/php.ini.  There are three of these for PHP versions 5.2 5.3 and 5.4 respectively.  Make the change in all of them (unless you know better).

You will need to stop and start Acquia Dev Desktop for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

### For php -v 7.0.3 users:

```
ssh: Brew update && upgrade
ssh: brew install homebrew/php/php70-xdebug
ssh: php -m
```

Check that the module is installed. Then copy the entire

```
usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.3/ content to - >
Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/

ssh: nano /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
```

configure `xdebug.so`:

```
ssh: sudo cp /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini     
/Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/bin/
```

DONE :-)