# Failed loading xdebug did found mach-o, but wrong architecture for php7

Tags: macos, php-7, acquia

Whether I install via homebrew:

```
brew install homebrew/php/php70-xdebug
```

or compile from source located at http://xdebug.org using either just `./configure` or the following:

```
./configure --enable-xdebug CC="gcc -arch i386" CXX="g++ -arch i386"
make
```

I still receive the following when running php7 that is bundled with Acquia DevDesktop:

```
Failed loading /Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/ext/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/ext/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/ext/xdebug.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Things I have confirmed:

- I am copying the xdebug.so into the proper directory either from /usr/local/Cellar/php70-xdebug/2.4.0 (in the case of the homebrew install)
- or from the newly compiled one from xdebug-2.4.0/module
- `which php` returns /Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/bin/php
- `php -i` shows the correct .ini file (/Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/bin/php.ini) and no others
- opcache.so is turned off
- `zend_extension="/Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/ext/xdebug.so"` is in the php.ini

The full message `php --version` returns is:

```
$ php --version
Failed loading /Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/ext/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/ext/xdebug.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/ext/xdebug.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
PHP 7.0.4 (cli) (built: Mar 18 2016 02:12:27) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

The OS is a brand-new install of Mac OS 10.11.5 on a MacBook Air.

Does anyone know why is it complaining about the wrong architecture?

Comment: do you still have a problem if you just set ./configure without sending the flags for the 32bit architecture?

Comment: did you manage to find a fix for this?

Comment: Somehow didn't get the emails. No, haven't found a resolution but haven't tried again since then. Performing debugging in 5.6. Going to check out the .so over at ActiveState.

Comment: The ActiveState xdebug.so didn't work and neither did removing the flags for the architecture.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me for DevDesktop:

1. Download and extract the xdebug source code (I used xdebug-2.5.5).
2. **$** `cd xdebug-2.5.5`
3. **$** `/Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/bin/phpize`

and now the step that was the one that caused most grief figuring out...

4. **$** `./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/bin/php-config CC="gcc -arch i386" CXX="g++ -arch i386"`
5. **$** `make`
6. **$** `cp modules/xdebug.so /Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/ext/`
7. open the `php7_0/bin/php.ini` file and (assuming it is the default) replace:

   `zend_extension="/Applications/DevDesktop/php5_6/ext/opcache.so"`

with

```
;zend_extension="/Applications/DevDesktop/php5_6/ext/opcache.so"
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/ext/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

8. Stop and Start the server instance in DevDesktop and debug away.

Answer (score 0):

```
• Open the php.ini file inside of Applications/DevDesktop/php(version#)/bin/php.ini
• Commented out the  following two lines:
    ○ zend_extension="/Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/ext/xdebug.so"
    ○ xdebug.remote_enable=1
• Stop and restart DevDesktop
```

The comments in this thread works for me.
Source: [Install XDebug and load in Acquia Drupal Stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180130/install-xdebug-and-load-in-acquia-drupal-stack)

Comment: DD doesn't currently ship with xdebug.so for PHP 7.